# ng new project - The system cannot find the path specified

Tags: angular, npm

I'm trying to create an angular 4 project using angular-cli on Windows 10.

I followed the steps provided in https://www.npmjs.com/package/@angular/cli.

I have node - 7.6.0 ; npm - 5.1.0.

Whenever I run `ng new my-app` , i get the following error
`G:\Projects\FS_20XX>"$basedir/../../Users/xxxxxx/AppData/Local/Yarn/config/global/node_modules/.bin/ng.cmd"   "$@" The system cannot find the path specified.`

I'm getting the same error when i use `ng help` too.

Could some one please help me.

Comment: It means ng has not been installed globally. Try this command once again: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Comment: I'v used this command npm install -g @angular/cli . and confirmed it is installed globally,

Comment: How did you confirm it? Do you see it listed when you do: `npm list -g`

Comment: @ankithsadashiva  Did you find the solution?

Answer (score 2):

Ther are a few steps to resolve this problem:-

1. Step-1. Uninstall  Angular CLI by using: `npm uninstall -g @angular/cli`
2. Step-2. clear npm cache by using: `npm cache clean --force`
3. Step-3. Uninstall  Node JS from control panel.
4. Step-4. Restart your PC.
5. Step-5. Install Node JS LTS Version - Recommended For Most Users form [here](https://nodejs.org/en/)!.
6. Step-6. Install Angular CLI by using: `npm install -g @angular/cli`

Now the problem resolved. "Happy Coding..."

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem for quite time.

The solution I found was that node was globally installed with `npm` and this caused conflicts.

- Check if you have two versions of node
- If you have, Go to your `npm` path `"%AppData%/Roaming/npm"` and the node and `node.cmd` file.